# iTextsharp is returning a null when getting the fonts from an existing PDF

Tags: itext

I'm working with some PDF files that return a null on the resources.GetAsDict(PdfName.FONT) method. I was able to use this same code on another set of PDF files created with the same composition tool.

```
    private static void ExtractFontNamesInPdf(string sourceFileName)
    {
        using (Stream pdfStream = new FileStream(sourceFileName, FileMode.Open))
        {
            var pdfReader = new PdfReader(pdfStream);
            var set = new List<BaseFont>();

            for (var index = 1; index <= pdfReader.NumberOfPages; index++)
            {
                var resources = pdfReader.GetPageN(index).GetAsDict(PdfName.RESOURCES);
                ProcessResource(set, resources);
            }

            foreach (var item in set)
                Console.WriteLine(item.PostscriptFontName + " " + item.FontType.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));

            Console.WriteLine("{0} Fonts found!", set.Count());
        }
    }

    private static void ProcessResource(ICollection<BaseFont> set, PdfDictionary resources)
    {
        if (resources == null)
            return;
        var xObjects = resources.GetAsDict(PdfName.XOBJECT);
        if (xObjects != null)
        {
            foreach (PdfName key in xObjects.Keys)
            {
                ProcessResource(set, xObjects.GetAsDict(key));
            }
        }

        var fonts = resources.GetAsDict(PdfName.FONT);

        if (fonts == null) return;

        foreach (PdfName key in fonts.Keys)
        {
            var iRef = (PRIndirectReference)fonts.Get(key);
            if (iRef != null)
                set.Add(BaseFont.CreateFont(iRef));
        }
    }
```

I can see a list of four fonts in Adobe Acrobat Pro. Though they are embedded and subset. These files are viewable and will print an high speed printer.

Comment: I'd recommend downloading [iText RUPS](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextrups/). Since you have named keys that you are looking for it might help to visualize the backing representation of them.

Comment: Please share the pdf in question if you cannot solve the issue using RUPS.

Comment: I wish I could share the PDF file, but it contains sensitive data.